# Deploy a Python app on App Engine leads to Error 500

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, plotly-dash

I want to deploy my Python app with Google App Engine. It works locally on the Google Cloud Shell. But with the URL generated with the command `google app deploy` I get the error 500. And in the logs, I can see:

```
import Dash
No module named dash
```

However, I already installed this module with the command `pip install dash`. 
My Python app uses version 2.7.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('abc.csv')  # csv file dataset

df.head()


classes = df['Class'].unique()

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

#layout part
#function part

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='127.0.0.4')
```

Comment: add dash to your requirements.txt and run command `pip install -r requirements.txt` https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/better-python-dependency-and-package-management-b5d8ea29dff1

Comment: @frankegoesdown The Python 2.7 runtime does not use `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Dash is not one of the [built-in third-party libraries in the Python 2.7 App Engine runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

You'll either need to follow [these instructions for bundling third-party libraries with your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), or switch to [the Python 3 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/).